# Bosonization at finite temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, temperature, bosonization

Textbook for bosonization mainly focus on the zero temperature limit. I wonder that at finite temperature, if there exists the boson-fermion dictionary as well.

Comment: Nothing significant changes at finite temperature. For that matter most of the textbook I can think of of the top of my head work in imaginary time, and so deal with the finite temperature case. You can even extend bosonization out of equilibrium, although that requires some more work